# Trust iOS App on iPhone with Work or school Account configured

Tags: iphone, enterprise, ios16

Can anyone let me know how can i trust an enterprise app installed on iPhone with Work or School account configured.

I am not getting Trust option in Settings and getting error - "Some restrictions are enforced by the profile "Google Apps Device Policy payload profile""

I want both my organisation app and company's gmail account in my iPhone

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question so much as a "how do I use an iPhone" kind of question. Maybe [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com)?